# Why do I have to write down the return type of the anonymous function in fold

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

Given this code in Scala:

```
package fpinscala.datastructures
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]

object Tree {

  def fold[A,B](t: Tree[A])(f: A => B)(g: (B,B) => B): B = {
    t match {
      case Leaf(x) => f(x)
      case Branch(l,r) => g(fold(l)(f)(g),fold(r)(f)(g))
    }
  }

  def mapViaFold[A,B](t:Tree[A])(f: A => B): Tree[B] = {
    fold(t)(a => Leaf(f(a)): Tree[B])(Branch(_,_))
  }

}
```

why do I have to write down the return type of the function `a => Leaf(f(a)): Tree[B]`? Without it I get the error message:

```
Error:(54, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : fpinscala.datastructures.Branch[B]
 required: fpinscala.datastructures.Leaf[B]
    fold(t)(a => Leaf(f(a)))(Branch(_,_))
                                   ^
```

Comment: Found the answer here: https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/datastructures/Tree.scala#L60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type parameter `B` in the fold definition is in that case inferred as `Leaf[B]` from the term `Leaf(f(a))`. You have then a type mismatch with the type of `Branch(_,_)`, `(Leaf[B],Leaf[B]) => Branch[B]`, that will never be a subtype of the required type `(Leaf[B], Leaf[B]) => Leaf[B]`.

**UPDATE**
I think the behaviour is due to how type reconstruction works in Scala: it is based on parameters lists (not on single parameters), and it goes from left to right. So once the compiler is able to infer some types for a parameter list, it will use them to resolve the types of the params list on the right, but not the other way around.

Below I've tried to extract the problem in the simpler form:

```
trait A
class B extends A
class C extends A

def f[T](x: T)(y: T): Int = 1
def g[T](x: T, y: T): Int = 1

f(new B)(new C) // Does not compile
g(new B, new C) // Compiles
```

In the curried version, `T` is inferred as `B` after the first parameter list, and we get then a type error in the second one.

In the unhurried version instead the compiler uses all the parameters in the unique parameters list to infer the type of T, that is in this case the least upper bound A, as we expected.

Comment: Why can't the compiler figure out that a supertype of Leaf[B] satisfies both expressions?

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I think is the reason, under the UPDATE section.